# How to create PDF document dynamically in PowerBuilder?

Tags: pdf, dynamic, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc, powerbuilder.net

We developed manufacturing ERP in PowerBuilder 10.5 and SQL Server.
And now we want to generate PDF file dynamically from datawindow and send it to the customer via e-mail attachment.
(we don't use PFC, we use our own framework)

Any help will be appreciable.

Any solutions?

Comment: It's look like really broad question (PDF generation and mail sending). Can you show what have you tried and make your question more specific?

Comment: we want to generate invoice and send it to the customer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install a PDF printer on the workstation; print the datawindow to this printer (thus creating a file); and then using OLE to create the email in Outlook, attach the file, then send it.  There are many examples online which show this type of functionality.